# Grunt fails to compile JST

Tags: gruntjs, jst

I'm trying to use JST templates for a project using Backbone. Everything seems to work allright, but I'm getting a syntax error which I can't wrap my head around.

This is what the console outputs:

```
Running "jst:compile" (jst) task
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
Warning: JST failed to compile. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running with --verbose

```
Verifying property jst.compile exists in config...OK
Files: templates/ideas/idea.jst -> scripts/templates/ideas/idea.js
Files: templates/ideas/idea_index.jst -> scripts/templates/ideas/idea_index.js
Options: namespace="JST", templateSettings={"interpolate":{}}, processContent=undefined, separator="\n\n", prettify, processName=undefined
Reading templates/ideas/idea.jst...OK
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
Warning: JST failed to compile. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

This is the file it is trying to compile:

```
<!-- IDEA START -->
<div class="ideadata" data-id="<%= id %>" data-date="<%= this.date %>" data-votes="<%= this.votes %>">

  <!-- Id -->
  <span class="id">#<%= this.id %></span>

  <!-- Idea -->
  <p><%= this.content %></p>

  <!-- Voting and social options -->
  <div class="social">
    <!-- VOTER -->
      <!-- HTML -->
    <!-- END -->

    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(
      'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&screen_name=roskildefestival&text=<%= this.content %>&tw_p=tweetbutton', 
      'twitter-share-dialog', 
      'width=550,height=390');
        return false;"><img src="http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/03-twitter-20.png" /></a>

    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436');
        return false;"><img src="http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/01-20.png" /></a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- IDEA END -->
```

I've tried replacing <%= with <% and this seems to be succesful, however this is not what I want to achieve.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this not the right way to write the JST template?

I used to use *.jst.eco as my template files when I was running on Rails, but since this is a PHP project I needed to figure out another way to do stuff, and therefore also unsure to wether this is the best way to do it or not.

**1ST EDIT:**

So after getting some feedback I've tried breaking it down to the simplest of the simple with this code:

```
<% if(true){ %>
  <div>Hey</div>
<% } %>
```

Which succeeds in compiling and gives me this:

```
this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};

this["JST"]["ideas/idea"] = function(obj) {obj || (obj = {});var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape, __j = Array.prototype.join;function print() { __p += __j.call(arguments, '') }with (obj) { if(true){ ;__p += '\n  <div>Hey</div>\n'; } ;}return __p};
```

And this, which fails to compile:

```
<div><%= this.id; %></div>
```

Comment: Try `grunt jst:compile --stack` as it should give you a stack trace on where the error is originating from.

Comment: Tried to run it with --verbose, nothing happened with --stack. I updated the question to match what it did output.

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down. Voting back up, I think it's a fine question.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this, the answer is in the github issue referenced in the comments. [github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst/issues/29]
The answer being:

If you want to parse templates just like _.template, then you must not overwrite templateSettings.

So I changed this:

```
      jst: {
        compile: {
          options: {
             templateSettings: {
               interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
             }
          },
          files: {
            "<%= buildDir %>/templates.js": ["source.html"]
          }
        }
      }
```

to this:

```
      jst: {
        compile: {
          options: {

          },
          files: {
            "<%= buildDir %>/templates.js": ["source.html"]
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Fantastic, this was the correct answer, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your error:

```
<!-- IDEA START -->
<div class="ideadata" data-id="<%= id %>"
```

Shouldn't it be `<%= this.id %>`? If it can't find `id` then it will be empty and therefore you will have an open `=`, which might cause the error?

Comment: Actually I just removed this. because I wanted to make sure that it wasn't causing any trouble. I get the same error with this. in front as well.

Comment: Hm, did you try to cut off the whole code block (file) and insert part by part (to see when that error occurs), it's primitve I know but that way you could figure out the conflict maybe?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question with the output I got from that, but it fails in even it's simplest form. I filed an issue at their github: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst/issues/29

Comment: I see :/ Maybe the scope of `this.` is not available? Maybe you have to use the `object's name`? But really can't help you out here, sorry

Comment: Well it shouldn't really have anything to do with compiling it, since I would then instead get a javascript error. I'll just have to wait and see about the issue!